# data not being stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Why isn't the data of the field `<select name="hr">` being stored?  If i create a new page with only the `<select name="hr">` and The local storage script, it works perfectly, but embeded with this code, it doesn't save the field.

```
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("hr").onchange = function() {
    localStorage['hr'] = document.getElementById("hr").value;
}
window.onload= function(){
    if(localStorage['hr'])
        document.getElementById("hr").value = localStorage['hr'];
}
</script>
<script>
var musicsrc = 'alarmtone.mp3'
function sivamtime() {
    now=new Date();
    hour=now.getHours();
    min=now.getMinutes();
    sec=now.getSeconds();

if (min<=9) {
    min="0"+min;
 }
if (sec<=9) {
    sec="0"+sec;
 }
if (hour>12) {
    hour=hour-12;
    add="pm";
 }
else {
    hour=hour;
    add="am";
 }
if (hour==12) {
    add="pm";
 }
if (hour==00) {
    hour="12";
 }

  document.hours.clock.value = (hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour;
  document.minutes.clock.value = min;
  document.seconds.clock.value = sec;
  document.ampm.clock.value= add;
 setTimeout("sivamtime()", 1000);

}

playit=false
function playmusic(){
musicwin=window.open("","","width=100,height=100")
musicwin.document.write('<embed src=\"'+musicsrc+'\" hidden="true" border="0" width="20" height="20" autostart="true" loop="true">')
musicwin.document.close()
}

function soundcheck(cbox){
playit=cbox.checked
}

function alarm() {

    hrs = document.arlm.hr.value;
    min = document.arlm.mts.value;
    apm = document.arlm.am_pm.value;

 if ((document.hours.clock.value == hrs) &&
    (document.minutes.clock.value == min) &&
    (document.ampm.clock.value == apm)) {
     if (playit)
     playmusic()
     return false}

setTimeout("alarm()", 1000);}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="sivamtime()">
<table border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="136">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">
                <b>Current Time</b>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="hours">
                <p><input type="text" size="2" name="clock"></p>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="minutes">
                <p><input type="text" size="2" name="clock" /></p>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="seconds">
                <p><input type="text" size="2" name="clock" /></p>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="ampm">
                <p><input type="text" size="2" name="clock" /></p>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="136">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <form name="arlm">
                <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">
                    <b>Alarm Time</b>
                </font>
        </td>

    </tr>  
    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">
                Hour 
            </font>
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">
                Minute
            </font>
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">
                am/pm
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
        <td>
            <select id="hr" name="hr" onFocus="select()">
                <option value="01">01</option>
                ...
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select name="mts" onFocus="select()">
                <option value="00">00</option>
                ...
                <option value="59">59</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select name="am_pm" onFocus="select()">
                <option value="am">AM</option>
                <option value="pm">PM</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="left">
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON" onClick="soundcheck(this)">
                <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, ms sans serif">Use music alert?</font>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">
            <input type="button" size="2" value="Set Alarm" onClick="alarm()" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3">
            <input type="button" size="2" value="Reset" onClick="reset()" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("hr").onchange = function() {
    localStorage['hr'] = document.getElementById("hr").value;
}
```

This is attempting to get an element from the DOM without it being ready.  You need to wait for the DOM to load before you attempt to access an elements 'onchange' attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but what should i do for delay the event?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the DOM not being ready yet when the onchange handler is added, the usage of localStorage seems to be wrong.

Instead of:

```
localStorage['hr'] = document.getElementById("hr").value;
```

Should be:

```
localStorage.setItem('hr', document.getElementById("hr").value);
```

Instead of:

```
if(localStorage['hr'])
```

Should be:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('hr'))
```

And so on...

Here you can find more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage

Comment: From your link: "Note: Although the values can be set and read using the standard JavaScript property access method, using the getItem and setItem methods is recommended."

Comment: Thanks! I missed that small note. :)